# Get the title of a td class with the Selenium Webdriver in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am very new to Selenium and Python in general. I want to get the title of a td class, the HTML code looks like this. I only need to get the 6,012,567 number to use later:

```
<td class="infoStats__stat link-light border-light-right">
  <a href=“/follow" class="infoStats__statLink link-light" title="6,012,567">
    <h3 class="infoStats__title font-light”>Users</h3>
    <div class="infoStats__value font-tabular-light">6.01M</div>
  </a>
</td>
```

So far I have this:

```
        #element = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//td[contains(@class, "infoStats__statLink")]')))

    #users = int(element.text.replace(',', ''))
```

But this is just giving me the 6.01 abbreviation, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following code to get required value:

```
value = int(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="infoStats__statLink link-light"]').get_attribute("title"))
```

Let me know if any errors occurs

Comment: I'm not sure on how to choose this answer as the solution, but this fixed it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @jorvdI think you should gain enough reputation score to be able to accept answers and do upvotes...

Answer (score 0):

Use the below XPath:-

```
//a[@class='infoStats__statLink link-light']/@title
```

Use code as below :-

```
elem =  driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='infoStats__statLink link-light']/@title");

print elem.text
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: This gave me the error message "Results in an Attribute, should be an Element"